# javascript: window.document returns null

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML document named 'welcome.html' that uses an iframe referring 'main.html'. Inside 'inner.html' file an another iframe is used referring 'inner.html'. Now inside 'inner.html' i want to access elements of / or communicate between elements of main.html. I used the following way to do so in javascript,

Method 1:

```
..
..
var top_window = window.top;
alert(top_window)    // gives top window object
var main_window = top_window.frames['main-frame'] // assuming that 'main-frame' is the name given at the iframe declaration for 'main.html'
alert(main_window)    // gives main window object
var main_document = main_window.document
alert(main_document)    // gives 'undefined'
..
..
```

Method 2:

```
..
..
var parent_window = window.parent;
alert(parent_window)    // gives parent window object, that is, 'main.html' window object
var parent_document = parent_window.document
alert(parent_document)    // gives 'null'
..
..
```

I want the document object of 'main.html's window object. Both my methods don't work out. Is there any sound solution or am I doing it in wrong manner?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though iframes is supported with the HTML5 doctype, I highly discourage using it.

Comment: does your code start after a `document.onload`?

Comment: can you point out the structure of the iframes? welcome.html->main.html ->? inner.html?

Comment: do frames open the same domain? if not - this might be the problem.

Comment: Is there a document loaded? are the urls of top and frame in the same domain?

Comment: @TimS. Then what are alternates?

Comment: @ToonCasteele: No, the code does not start after a document.onload.

Comment: then why do you wonder why the document is null? You should always start your js code after a `document.onload`. Possibly this is not the problem, but still...

Comment: @pfried: Yes, the same structure is being followed.

Comment: @RuslanPolutsygan: Yes, frames open the same domain only.

Comment: @thomas: Yes, frames open the same domain only.

Comment: @dsharma4u29 Alternatives? Load dynamic content with PHP, and if you desperately want to avoid page refreshes, try AJAX.

Comment: @TimS. Suppose there is no server involvement, then?

Comment: @pfried : Actually 'parent.document' is not working (being called from a child iframe to parent iframe) in Chrome but in Mozilla. I need solution for Chrome only now.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to communicate between the iframe s is by getting the window objects. Create a getter setter function in both the parent and the child and pass the values between the two window objects.

This will return the window object of the iframe

```
var contentWindow = document.getElementbyId('iframe').contentWindow
```

From the iframe access the parent window by using `window.parent`